# Scale the Bitmap to screen in Live wallpaper

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I'm new in Android Programming I'm Trying to make slideshow animated live wallpaper and all ok but the problem is when I set the wallpaper the scale of image is stretched to screen I want it to scale to all the phone screens and when swipe the wallpaper get the right part of image I Want Advice about this problem.
my code is :

```
public class CustomWallpaper extends WallpaperService {

@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    return new WallpaperEngine();
}

class WallpaperEngine extends Engine {
    //Duration between slides in milliseconds
    private final int SLIDE_DURATION = 8;

    private int[] mImagesArray;
    private int mImagesArrayIndex = 0;
    private Thread mDrawWallpaper;
    private String mImageScale = "Fit to screen";
    private CustomWallpaperHelper customWallpaperHelper;

    public WallpaperEngine() {
        customWallpaperHelper = new CustomWallpaperHelper(getApplicationContext(), getResources());
        mImagesArray = new int[] {R.drawable.image_1,R.drawable.image_2,R.drawable.image_3,R.drawable.image_4,R.drawable.image_5,R.drawable.image_6,R.drawable.image_7,R.drawable.image_8,R.drawable.image_9,R.drawable.image_10,R.drawable.image_11,R.drawable.image_12,R.drawable.image_13,R.drawable.image_14,R.drawable.image_15,R.drawable.image_16,R.drawable.image_17,R.drawable.image_18,R.drawable.image_19,R.drawable.image_20,R.drawable.image_21,R.drawable.image_22,R.drawable.image_23,R.drawable.image_24,R.drawable.image_25,R.drawable.image_26,R.drawable.image_27,R.drawable.image_28,R.drawable.image_29,R.drawable.image_30,R.drawable.image_31,R.drawable.image_32,R.drawable.image_33,R.drawable.image_34,R.drawable.image_35,R.drawable.image_36,R.drawable.image_37,R.drawable.image_38,R.drawable.image_39,R.drawable.image_40,R.drawable.image_41};

        mDrawWallpaper = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        drawFrame();
                        incrementCounter();
                        Thread.sleep(SLIDE_DURATION);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //
                }
            }
        });

        mDrawWallpaper.start();
    }

    private void incrementCounter() {
        mImagesArrayIndex++;

        if (mImagesArrayIndex >= mImagesArray.length) {
            mImagesArrayIndex = 0;
        }
    }

    private void drawFrame() {
        final SurfaceHolder holder = getSurfaceHolder();

        Canvas canvas = null;

        try {
            canvas = holder.lockCanvas();

            if (canvas != null) {
                drawImage(canvas);
            }
        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }

    private void drawImage(Canvas canvas) {
        //Get the image and resize it
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                mImagesArray[mImagesArrayIndex]);



        //Draw background
        customWallpaperHelper.setBackground(canvas);

        //Scale the canvas
        PointF mScale = customWallpaperHelper.getCanvasScale(mImageScale, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        canvas.scale(mScale.x, mScale.y);

        //Draw the image on screen
        Point mPos = customWallpaperHelper.getImagePos(mScale, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, mPos.x, mPos.y, null);


    }
}

}
```

and the other class is:

```
public class CustomWallpaperHelper {
    public final static String IMAGE_SCALE_STRETCH_TO_SCREEN = "Stretch to   screen";

public final static String IMAGE_SCALE_FIT_TO_SCREEN = "Fit to screen";

private Context mContext;
private Resources mResources;

private Point screenSize = new Point();

private Bitmap bgImageScaled;
private Point bgImagePos = new Point(0, 0);

public CustomWallpaperHelper(Context mContext, Resources mResources) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mResources = mResources;

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    screenSize.x = display.getWidth();
    screenSize.y = display.getHeight();

    ;
}

private void scaleBackground() {
    String imageScale = "Stretch to screen";
    Bitmap bgImage = null;

    if (imageScale.equals(IMAGE_SCALE_STRETCH_TO_SCREEN)) {
        bgImagePos = new Point(0, 0);
        bgImageScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bgImage, screenSize.x, screenSize.y, true);
    }
}

public void setBackground(Canvas canvas) {
    if (bgImageScaled != null) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(bgImageScaled, bgImagePos.x, bgImagePos.y, null);
    } else {
        canvas.drawColor(0xff000000);
    }
}

public int getScreenWidth() {
    return screenSize.x;
}

public int getScreenHeight() {
    return screenSize.y;
}

public Point getImagePos(PointF canvasScale, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
    Point imagePos = new Point();

    imagePos.x = (int) (screenSize.x - (imageWidth * canvasScale.x)) / 2;
    imagePos.y = (int) (screenSize.y - (imageHeight * canvasScale.y)) / 2;

    return imagePos;
}

public PointF getCanvasScale(String imageScale, int imageWidth, int imageHeight) {
    PointF canvasScale = new PointF(1f, 1f);

    if (imageScale.equals(IMAGE_SCALE_STRETCH_TO_SCREEN)) {
        canvasScale.x = getScreenWidth() / (1f * imageWidth);
        canvasScale.y = getScreenHeight() / (1f * imageHeight);
    } else {
        boolean tooWide = false;
        boolean tooTall = false;

        if (getScreenWidth() < imageWidth) {
            tooWide = true;
        }

        if (getScreenHeight() < imageHeight) {
            tooTall = true;
        }

        if (tooWide && tooTall) {
            int x = imageWidth / getScreenWidth();
            int y = imageHeight / getScreenHeight();

            if (x > y) {
                canvasScale.x = getScreenWidth() / (1f * imageWidth);
                canvasScale.y = 1;
            } else {
                canvasScale.x = 1;
                canvasScale.y = getScreenHeight() / (1f * imageHeight);
            }
        } else if (tooWide) {
            canvasScale.x = getScreenWidth() / (1f * imageWidth);
            canvasScale.y = 1;
        } else if (tooTall) {
            canvasScale.x = 1;
            canvasScale.y = getScreenHeight() / (1f * imageHeight);
        }
    }

    return canvasScale;
}
}
```

I want Advice for this problem.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

no need to do anything just Replace your below method with my code.

```
private void drawImage(Canvas canvas)
     {

            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    mImagesArray[mImagesArrayIndex]);
            Bitmap b=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), true);
            canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0,0, null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you crop the images instead of resizing them. Something like:

```
Rect r = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
Bitmap croppedImage = null;
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1){
    InputStream in = mContentResolver.openInputStream(mSaveUri);
    BitmapRegionDecoder decoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(in, false);
    croppedImage = decoder.decodeRegion(r, null);
} else {
    final int width = r.width();
    final int height = r.height();
    croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, r.left, r.top, width, height);
croppedImage.setDensity(croppedImage.getDensity() * mOutputX / width);
}
return croppedImage;
```

Hope this helps...